# TIBCO Spotfire Advanced Data Services = data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, ssas, tibco, spotfire

This [document](http://spotfire.tibco.com/assets/blt12dd22462cf59291/app-data-services.pdf) states that the TIBCO Spotfire Advanced Data Services:

"Eliminates the need to pre-build a data warehouse"

Can TIBCO Spotfire Advanced Data Services really achieve the same performance, flexibility as for example a data warehouse build in sql server (as far as SSAS in tabular mode)?

Is TIBCO Spotfire Advanced Data Services a true data consolidation layer or more a data federation layer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced Data Services is the Spotfire term for Cisco Information Server V6.1, which they bought from Composite some point in the last year or so.

It allows you to create a 'virtual' warehouse of definable views from a large variety of sources, meaning that you can create Spotfire readable tables of almost any schema.  It can create joins on almost any type of data, from hadoop type systems to web services, and to surface them up to Spotfire as flat tables

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I learned this in the meantime. Even Tibco's experts told me that it is not as scalable as a 'proper' data warehouse. This seem to be the case for literally all 'Data Federation' layers.